# how to move an element under other element with the transform property

Tags: css, transform

I use sly jquery plugin , this plugin sets the transform property for one element
and then this element goes on top of all the other elements

I have one element that I want to be on top of this element

properties of the element that I want to be on top

CSS...

```
width: 235px;
height: 55px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1900px;
```

and properties of the element that is on top (that's what I don't want)

```
transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(0px);
width: 1710px;height:100%;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say what is the correct answer.

Anyway, z-index is an abstract property, and only uses numbers (not pixels).

The correct syntax is:

```
z-index: 1900;
```

That, by the way, is a very high value for a z-index. You only need to set it higher than other values.